# How do I disable storing my messages on iCloud?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

I try not to use iCloud. I like to back up all my photos and files manually into my external hard drives, so I don't have any use for it. But over the last 2 months, I've been getting bombarded by alerts, e-mails, pop-ups, notifications, and every other possible method to warn me that my iCloud is almost full.

I finally checked my iCloud storage, and it says 4.53GB of it is messages.

[image]

I don't want a cloud backup of my texts. I use iMessage on my iPhone and my Macbook.

How do I stop iCloud storing these messages?

Comment: Either delete some messages or stop storing them in iCloud. iMessage will still work, but each device will only store a local copy of its messages. [It's pretty clear what your options are](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208960), also: [*if "messages" consume too much storage, don't delete your conversations just yet"*](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/if-messages-consumes-too-much-iphone-icloud-storage-dont-delete-your-conversations-just-yet-0384614/)

Answer (score 1):

Logging into icloud.com won't give access to manage the storage. This has to be done on the iPhone's system preferences. First tap the user's Apple ID at the top of the settings, then iCloud. In there you can manage your storage, and delete all backed-up messages (it'll give you a 30-day period to undo this deletion). You can also disable other apps that back up their data via iCloud. You can see at the top of the `Storage` bar that now it's only using 467MB after deleting all the messages:

[image]
[image]